# Metadata for columns in SQLite v2.8 (PHP5)

Tags: php, sqlite, metadata, sqlite2

How can I get metadata / constraints (primary key and "null allowed" in particular) for each column in a SQLite v2.8 table using PHP5 (like mysql_fetch_field for MySql)?

`sqlite_fetch_column_types` (OO: `$db->fetchColumnTypes`) only gets column name and datatype:
http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-fetch-column-types.php

SQLITE_MASTER has the info - but not as a variable. Example:
`SELECT name FROM SQLITE_MASTER;`

... SQLITE_MASTER only outputs an array with this structure (v2.8):

```
[type] => table
[name] => foo
[tbl_name] => foo
[rootpage] => 3
[sql] => CREATE TABLE foo ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name CHAR(255) )
```

(And what is "rootpage"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this to implement a `describeTable()` method for SQLite when I worked on Zend Framework.  SQLite does not have any way to get very detailed information about metadata.

What I did was to run the following SQLite query:

```
PRAGMA tableinfo( <tablename> );
```

See http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html, under the heading "Pragmas to query the database schema."

The result set returned from this query has columns for:

- column position (integer)
- column name (string)
- data type (string)
- nullable (0) vs. not null (1)
- default value (string)
- primary key (1)

You can view the PHP code by downloading Zend Framework and looking in class `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Sqlite`, method `describeTable()`.  You can also view the source online via the code repository browser at framework.zend.com (although it is frequently not working).

FWIW, this is not like `mysql_fetch_field()`.  That method returns metadata about a result set, which may not be the same thing as metadata about a table.

Answer (score 1):

Example code snippet that worked for me ... to illustrate Bill Karwin's solution (it's not an attempt to answer my own question!)

```
$db = new SQLiteDatabase("db.sqlite2");  
$rs = $db->arrayQuery("PRAGMA table_info( 'my_table' );");
print_r($rs);
```